# C Printfs are expecting a Type Specifier

Tags: c

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my C code here. The last two `printf` calls are asking for a type specifier and I don't know what to give it. The other lines don't have this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Edit The program does multiple math functions and the two print lines in question are supposed to print the results of two of these equations. The first one is supposed to print the remainder of the two numbers the user enters, the second printf is supposed to print out the answer of adding the two numbers together, multiplying that by the first number, and dividing it by the second number. Both of these printf lines give me the error of E0079, expected a type specifier.

Edit 2: Solved this issue by changing my SDK pack for the project, and also putting the calculations after asking the user for the numbers. Jimmy's formatting tips also helped fix it. Thank you so much to all of you who helped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(void) {

    int digit1; //First digit user gives
    int digit2; //Second digit user gives.
    int product; //The result of the two user given numbers multiplied.
    int cube; //The result of cubing the second number.
    int remainder; //The remainder of dividing the two given numbers.
    int tooManySteps; //The result of adding the two given numbers together, multiplying it by the first given number, dividing by the second number.

    product = digit1 * digit2;
    cube = digit2 * digit2 * digit2;
    remainder = digit1 % digit2;
    tooManySteps = (digit1 + digit2) * digit1 / digit2;

    printf("Hi there, want me to do some cool math for you? Great! Just give me a number please.");
    scanf("%d", &digit1);

    printf("Cool! Now just give me one number.");
    scanf("%d", &digit2);

    printf("Your numbers multiplied together give you %d \n", product);

    printf("Now the cube of the second number you gave is %d \n", cube);

    printf("If you were to divide your two numbers together your remainder would be %d\n", remainder);

    printf("Now we'll get really crazy, if you were to add your two numbers, multiply them by the first number you gave and divide by the second number you gave, you would get %d\n", tooManySteps);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: OT I don't think it's a good idea to do the calculations before asking for the number :-)

Comment: [Your code is not giving any error](https://ideone.com/JQXeMF) except you forget `int` before `int main(void)` and `return 0` at the end of main.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Closing if no further info provided.

Comment: Start using the gdb to debug this. simple `gcc-g your_file.c` and run `gdb ./a.out`. then enter r and then do bt full it will show you what is the problem is.

Comment: Your code causing Floating point exception (core dumped)

Comment: @LethalProgrammer It's UB. Division by indeterminate value.... But the OP is complaining about compilation.

Comment: `Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000400632 in main () at test.c:15
15 remainder = digit1 % digit2;
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x0000000000400632 in main () at test.c:15
        digit1 = 4196112
        digit2 = 0
        product = 0
        cube = 0
        remainder = -7536
        tooManySteps = 32767`

Comment: I added more details about what I'm trying to do. I put in the whole code cause I'm not sure what in the code is causing the errors in those two printf lines.

Comment: Your code as shown should not produce the error claimed.  Which compiler are you using and which platform are you using it on.  You shouldn't do the calculations before you read the data.  As written, you have seriously undefined behaviour (using uninitialized variables), and you might incur a division by zero error.  But the missing type specifier sounds like a compilation error.  Are you sure you're compiling the right code?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community on a Windows 10 PC. I put my calculations after the parts asking the user for the two numbers, and now the third to last printf line is giving the same "expected a type specifier" error, it doesn't say anything other than that, but it has a link for E0079 which just leads to a Bing search page with Stock Overflow threads that don't have the same error (none of them talk about printf errors). I'm sorry, but I don't understamd the uninitialized variable part of your reply, I initialized all of my variables with int -variable name-; statements. Is that bad?

Comment: Also I am trying to use these Stock Overflow threads for hints to what may be wrong with my code, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think it's a bad question. But I still correct the code for you.

```
int main(void)
{
    int digit1; //First digit user gives
    int digit2; //Second digit user gives.
    int product; //The result of the two user given numbers multiplied.
    int cube; //The result of cubing the second number.
    int remainder; //The remainder of dividing the two given numbers.
    int tooManySteps; //The result of adding the two given numbers together,
                      //multiplying it by the first given number, 
                      //dividing by the second number.

    printf("Hi there, want me to do some cool math for you? Great! "
           "Just give me a number please.");
    scanf("%d", &digit1);

    printf("Cool! Now just give me one number.");
    scanf("%d", &digit2);

    product = digit1 * digit2;
    cube = digit2 * digit2 * digit2;
    remainder = digit1 % digit2;
    tooManySteps = (digit1 + digit2) * digit1 / digit2;

    printf("Your numbers multiplied together give you %d \n", product);

    printf("Now the cube of the second number you gave is %d \n", cube);

    printf("If you were to divide your two numbers together your "
           "remainder would be %d\n", remainder);

    printf("Now we'll get really crazy, if you were to add your two numbers, "
           "multiply them by the first number you gave and divide by the second"
           " number you gave, you would get %d\n",
           tooManySteps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should explain the changes – the most critical one being to move the read operations (`scanf()` calls) before using the results in the computations.